# SSAS require special privileges to create/edit a named query?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012, ssas, ssms

I am trying to make modifications to a named query in a cube and the data source view (.dsv) won't allow me to make edits or create a new named query. It gives me a login error even though I can successfully do a test connection in the data source dialog and can login successfully with SSMS.

The error is: "Login failed for user "

If I instead use the Windows authentication I am able to do everything; however, I would like to use the SQL Server Authentication option.

Are there privileges that need to be set for this?  I'm pretty sure I've tried giving this user everything from db_owner etc in my local environment and still no luck.

I was wondering if maybe SSAS requires a specific role to allow SQL Server Authentication to be used for editing/creating named queries in the data source view.

Comment: SSAS doesn't support SQL Authentication. It's windows authentication all the way.

Comment: Preet Sangha - Are you referring to only client reporting tools can connect via Windows Authentication.  I am referring to the database connection I'm using during my cube development. Both authentication options are supported for db connection authentication.

Comment: I've only ever used window authentication, so I might be wrong in that particular area

Comment: I'm just thinking out loud, but have you tried it with the SA account?

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to the following steps to slove this issue:

1. In the SSDT development interface, double-click on your data source.
2. In the Data Source Desginer dialog, please click "Edit".
3. Please select "SqlClient Data Provider", and then use your SQL Account for the data source.

Follow this link
(https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b5f05388-42e0-4fb6-92a9-d7d3e08aa98c/ssdt-2012-named-query-problem?forum=sqlanalysisservices)

Comment: it faild dimensions creating.